# IOS - Download file then showing it on UIWebView

Tags: ios

I have a code that downloads a file and store it in the documents folder:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:file.url]];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, file.name];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];
[operation start];
```

When the request is completed, I want to show that same file on a UIWebView using this code:

```
[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
   NSURL *targetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:file.nameWithoutExtension withExtension:@"pdf"];
   webView.delegate = self;
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
   [webView loadRequest:request];

   ViewerVC* viewer = [[ViewerVC alloc] init];
   [viewer.view addSubview:webView];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewer animated:FALSE];
 });
});
```

But it does not work, the URL does not find the file I just downloaded, Am i saving or searching it wrong?

(The code is slightly different from my actual code for understanding purposes, but the idea is the same. I even tried this example with some hard coded URL, like: http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:file.nameWithoutExtension withExtension:@"pdf"]` will give you file from your **xcode project folder**.

Use this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *fileName = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourFileName.pdf"];
```

It will get you a file from Documents folder.

Comment: Thank you! I could use the filePath from the first code! Just doing that: NSURL* targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]; solved my problem.

Comment: @ViniciusPaiva And please use `YES` and `NO` for `BOOL` values instead of `false` or `FALSE` ;)